# Why is a C++ MFC "empty" project taking up 142MB and a 6MB executable? (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

As comparison, making the same basic Windows Forms application from VS2010 C# is literally 600 kilobytes. For #1 and #2 below, I created a fresh dialog-based MFC app called "hello". The combined project folder size is 142MB.

So I guess this question is 2-part:

1) Why are these "necessary" and so huge, for a tiny, essentially functionless, program:

```
hello.sdf - 61MB
hello.pch - 32MB
hello.pbd - 24MB
hello.ilk - 14MB
hello.exe - 6MB
```

2) Ultimately my goal is to distribute a static exe that will run on XP/2000/7/8 as well as running in Wine (for Mac/Linux systems) -- would MFC or Win32 be better for this?

This will be a Forms & Dialogs app (as opposed to graphics and whatnot) and will be mostly just reading and writing to text files.

Comment: Is that hello.exe static and debug? What's it look like when you do a release mode build?

Comment: Are you by any chance building and measuring the Debug configuration?

Comment: The only file that is relevant to your needs is `hello.exe`. The rest are produced as part of the build process; they are not to be distributed. Also, your program is neither "tiny" nor "functionless". Just because it doesn't do anything that you would consider meaningful doesn't mean it isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: @AndreyT Yes, is there another way to generate the .exe?

Comment: @user1502648: Another way would be to build a Release configuration, which will be significantly more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are none of your concern in regards to your executable size. You don't distribute them to your users.  You're measuring intellisense database files, the pre-compiled header file, a SQL database file, and a file used by the linker.  Build a release version and look at your .exe file.  That's all that matters.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. It just freaked me out and confused me to see all that data generated for a tiny program. I'd never seen that before even with VC# Express 2010.

I'm actually looking at the execs right now and this is what is still confusing, then:
hello.exe (new MFC Application project, no changes made simply hit Build/Debug/SaveAll) is 6MB, whereas test.exe (new Win32 API project, no changes made simply hit Build/Debug/SaveAll) is 90KB.

Comment: @user - The size of a debug build isn't very interesting, as that is not what you are going to distribute.

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to generate an executable... in C# you have Publish but I see no comparable options in C++...

Comment: @user1502648: Set your configuration to release mode.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses and information, I really appreciate it. I had trouble getting Release to "stick" (it changes back to 'Active (Debug)' setting after changing) but yes that brought the size down to 1.6MB

Answer (score 0):

`hello.sdf` is an internal visual-studio database file to keep all the cross references of the source - it includes all .h headers from SDK that your sample source is connected with.

Try to build release, non-Unicode with shared libraries.

Comment: Do you know of anywhere here or elsewhere online that is discussed the uses of MFC versus Win32 API? I need a static/standalone exe that can be run on current (W7/W8) systems as well as old (2k/XP) systems, and also people running Wine (Linux/Mac).

Comment: MFC is a C++ Win32 wrapper to make programming easy :) Because poor API is C-based, not C++. You have to build it static to be standalone or attach mfc100.dll for shared-build programm.

Comment: VC++ 2010 projects won't run under Windows 2000 without some hacking.

Comment: @Luke thanks I didn't know that. No love for 2k is actually surprising, considering how long they supported it.

Comment: @sublay Okay, so it sounds like I should just use MFC then anyway, because while I'm not new to coding in general, it's been ten years since I did C++ so I'm "new" to it, because last time I used was doing mostly just C and in VS6.0